# Python: Create Dictionary from Text/File that's in Dictionary Format

Tags: python, file, dictionary, external

I'd like to create a dictionary from a text file that I have, who's contents are in a 'dictionary' format. Here's a sample of what the file contains:

> {'fawn': [1], 'sermersheim': [3], 'sonji': [2], 'scheuring': [2]}

It's exactly this except it contains 125,000 entries. I am able to read in the text file using read(), but it creates a variable of the literal text of the file even when I initialize the variable with

> dict = {}

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @JBernardo +1 as long as you have Python 2.6 or newer, that's the way to go. The `ast` module was introduced in 2.5, but didn't have the helper functions (such as `literal_eval`). Those came in 2.6.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) built-in. For example, this would work if each dictionary entry is on a different line:

```
dicts_from_file = []
with open('myfile.txt','r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        dicts_from_file.append(eval(line))    
# dicts_from_file now contains the dictionaries created from the text file
```

Alternatively, if the file is just one big dictionary (even on multiple lines), you can do this:

```
with open('myfile.txt','r') as inf:
    dict_from_file = eval(inf.read())
```

This is probably the most simple way to do it, but it's not the safest. As others mentioned in their answers, `eval` has some inherent security risks. The alternative, as mentioned by JBernardo, is to use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which is much safer than eval since it will only evaluate strings which contain literals. You can simply replace all the calls to `eval` in the above examples with `ast.literal_eval` after importing the `ast` module.

If you're using Python 2.4 you are not going to have the `ast` module, and you're not going to have [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statements. The code will look more like this:

```
inf = open('myfile.txt','r')
dict_from_file = eval(inf.read())
inf.close()
```

Don't forget to call `inf.close()`. The beauty of `with` statements is they do it for you, even if the code block in the `with` statement raises an exception.

Comment: What if it's just a wall o' text? It's literally just a solid string starting with { and ending with }.

Comment: It will work if there's only one line, though it won't work if the dictionary is spread out over more than one line. I added additional code for that case.

Comment: I'm getting an 'invalid syntax' with the > "with open('myfile.txt','r') as inf: line.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.5 or newer?

Comment: @Jared I edited my answer to include some notes about using a version of Python older than 2.5, which it seems you may have. Basically, you won't have `with` statements (not too important), and you won't have the `ast` module.

Comment: Yes, you win the Pickle @Series8217. I have 2.4 on this computer and 2.5 at my other (primary), so I was unaware "with" would not work!

Comment: FYI: it looks like the method is now `ast.literal_eval`, not `ast.literaleval`

Comment: Got error: "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes"

Answer (score 3):

Use the [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) function.

For example,

```
dict = eval(open("yourfile.txt").read())
```

Comment: +1 `eval` is definitely the simplest thing to do.  The comment made by @JBernardo about `ast.literal_eval` is safer though as it only allows for strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.  Just something to consider.

Answer (score 3):

Using `eval` might be dangerous. If json doesn't work, then I'd recommend using [yaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) which seems to work fine with your example input:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load("{'fawn': [1], 'sermersheim': [3], 'sonji': [2], 'scheuring': [2]}")
{'fawn': [1], 'scheuring': [2], 'sermersheim': [3], 'sonji': [2]}
```

Comment: Ah, I'd like to use this but I don't have the module and the system the code is being run on has no internet access. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You might want to consider installation from source anyway. According to the documentation, it should be as easy as: `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a production ready solution and may not work well with a file of your size, but if you need a simple way and can prepend you file to

```
my_dict = {'fawn': [1], 'sermersheim': [3], 'sonji': [2], 'scheuring': [2]}
```

then you can rename it to a python file and simply import

```
from my_file import my_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly discourage using `eval` though. It may result in security issues if you don't have full control on the input file. Just import your dictionary and save them by using the `json` or `pickle` module.

Comment: I agree that eval is a giant security risk if used on a regular basis or in production code, I interpreted the original question to be dealing with an isolated bit of code that comes from a trusted source and is already in a text file.  Given such a situation, there's not much else you can do.

Comment: It is in a static file from a trusted source, yes!

Comment: And I've had no luck with pickle files. I have this same information in a .pickle file, but can't seem to get it to load back in. This code is being ran on a restricted system with no internet access.

Comment: @Jared Perhaps you should post a question about your problems with `pickle` since that seems to be the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This looks like json to me. Use the `json` module if so.</strike>

This looks like  yaml to me. Use the [pyyaml module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML) if so. (As suggested by @jcollado).

You can't use the `json` module because it is strict about its input.

Comment: It's not JSON: it uses single-quotes instead of double-quotes.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Yes. I didn't realise that the `json` module was strict about its input.