# Personalized Attachments to Each Recipient From Outlook using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

Consider the following scenario:

**User 1:**

> From Address = "sender@domain.com"
>
> To Address = "Receiver_1@domain.com"
>
> Attachment = "*common path --> file_1"*

**User 2:**

> From Address = "sender@domain.com"
>
> To Address = "Receiver_2@domain.com"
>
> Attachment = "*common path --> file_2"*

How do i execute the above task if it is to be carried out for 500 unique users, with 500 unique attachments (1 unique attachment per unique user)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: vba quick example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303646/4539709

Comment: work with dictionary- load ur to address & attachment to dictionary then send out each email -

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop over 500 recipients and send a separate message to each address.

Comment: Could you help me out with the code? i am not sure how to write one loop for recipients and another loop for the attachments..

Answer (score 0):

Use [mailmerge](http://%20https://pypi.org/project/mailmerge/). It's a python programme to send individualized e-mails; you don't need outlook for that.

Answer (score 0):

*[Python: Create Dictionary from Text/File that's in Dictionary Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314824/python-create-dictionary-from-text-file-thats-in-dictionary-format)*

*quick example-*

```
import win32com.client

dictionary_list = {"Receiver_1@domain.com": r"C:\Temp\2019.pdf", "Receiver_2@domain.com": r"C:\Temp\2019.pdf", }
ol_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

for key in dictionary_list:
    value = dictionary_list[key]
    email = ol_app.CreateItem(0)
    email.To = key
    email.Subject = "subject"
    email.HtmlBody = ""
    email.Attachments.Add(value)
    email.Display()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But does this mean, i will have to declare 500 values & keys in the dictionary list?